# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, compilation

I am using Jenkins ver. 1.565.11.1 (Jenkins Enterprise by CloudBees 14.05) and have JDK 1.5,1.5.0.22,1.6,1.7 all are installed and using different versions for different projects.

My question is I compiled one project with JDK 1.7 by mistake but I have to compile it using jdk 1.5 but not able to do it. Getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number     in .class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:242)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.main(Maven31Main.java:138)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.main(Maven31Main.java:67)
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:331)
at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:280)
at hudson.slaves.Channels.forProcess(Channels.java:114)
at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:280)
at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:755)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1706)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:232)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Kindly suggest what should i change in jenkins project configuration so that project will compile with jdk 1.5 .... only able to change project configuration not jenkins main configuratoin for jdk..

Comment: What version of maven3 are you using? Version 3.1.1 was that last to support executing with jdk 1.5.

Comment: I think that classes in your libraries are compiled by newer version of Java (> 1.5). So, search old libraries.

Comment: I am using maven version 3.2 <version>3.2</version>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven 3.2 requires at least jdk 1.6 for execution.

If you want to use maven 3.2 (or newer) and compile code using the 1.5 jdk, you can look at using [toolchains](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html).